# Motorola EX115 USB driver not installing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-storage, mobile-phone

I am using a Moto EX115 mobile phone from Motorola. I need to use my mobile's internet connection on the PC. But when I plug in the USB data cable it says

> USB driver is not installed properly

My OS: Windows 7 (32 Bit). I need suggestions for both 64 and 32 Bit.

Where can I get a USB driver and how can I install it on my PC?

I followed [the steps here](http://modmymobile.com/forums/8-guides-downloads-forum-suggestions/521428-install-motorola-usb-drivers-windows-7-a.html) but it didn't help.

Is there any Moto users please help me!

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.motorola.com/consumers/v/...008806b00aRCRD

Comment: @avirk: Yes just last night.But no reply is yet.

Comment: Motorola always give driver disk. Have you got that. If yes then try to install in compatible mode and when these install then try to connect your device.

Comment: http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Software/Motorola-Phone-Tools-version-5-US-EN    Download driver on this link for motorola phones.

Comment: Use Alcatel PC Suite & configure settings under connect to internet option & voila ur online...enjoy...

Comment: @AMotoUser:that's great news.I will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Alcatel PC Suite v7.0.2](http://www.techibuzz.com/alcatel-pc-suite-v7-free-download/) for syncing.

Answer (score -1):

Very bad.

There is **no option in Moto EX115 mobile model** to connect internet in pc.

*Be aware before buying mobile*